# Nested for loops to iterate to the power of 2

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I need to use two loops in such a way that the outer loop drives the inner loop to do computations for 2,4,8,16,and 32 iterations.

for example if i=2(for outer loop)
then inner loop will iterate for 4 times

and if i=3
then inner loop will iterate for 8 times and so on.

this is the logic I m using

```
for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) 
     {
         for ( c = 0 ; c <= pow(2,i) ; c=c++ )
```

I would really appreciate any suggestions

Comment: There's a syntax error: the closing brackets are missing from both of the for loops.

Comment: What task should these loops accomplish, specifically?

Comment: `c = c++` is not what you wanted.  Instead of `pow(2, i)`, write `(1 << i)`.  Meditate a little on why shifting 1 left by i gives you the ith power of two.

Answer (score 1):

1. Compute the number of iterations of the inner loop once and reuse it instead of computing it everytime.
2. Don't use `pow(2, i)`. Use the more reliable `1 << i`.
3. Don't use `c = c++`. Just use `c++`. I am not sure `c = c++` is guaranteed to be `c = c+1`.

```cpp
for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) 
{
   int nextCount = (1 << i);
   for ( c = 0 ; c <= nextCount ; c++ )
```

Comment: @user2373210, that's strange. `(1 << 1)` is `2`, `(1 << 2)` is `4`, and so on. I can't think of any reason why you would get `2^-1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that to compute a small power of two in C++ you can use a bit shift left:

```
for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) {
    for ( c = 0 ; c < (1 << i) ; c++ ) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The reason behind this "magic" is the same as the reason why adding a zero to the right of a decimal number multiplies the number by ten.

Note that since you start the iteration of the inner loop at zero, you need to use `<`, not `<=`. Otherwise you would iterate 2<sup>n</sup>+1 times.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use something like everyone else has suggested:

```
for (int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
    for(int c=0 ; c < (1<<i) ; c++){
        //do computations
    }
}
```

The reason you want to use `<` instead of `<=` is becase `<=` will actually give you (2^i)+1 iterations, due to counting zero.

The reason you want to want to use the bitshift operation `1<<i`, is because integers are already in base two, and adding zeros on the end is the equivelant of multiplying by two repeatedly. (1 is automatically created as an integer, while 1.0 is automatically created as a float. You could not safely do this with floats: 1.0<<1 bitshifts to 1.70141e+38, if you can get the compiler to do it.)

Finally, you want to use `c++` because c++ increments c, but returns the original value, so your inner for-loop always keeps the original value and never increments.